# How to make a dynamic rich card

Tags: asp.net, carousel, botframework, bots

I am trying to create a rich card carousel. I have my data in an array and I want a new card to be generated dynamically in accordance to the size of my array.

This is my sample carousel code which returns only one card.

```
var attachment = new List<Attachment>()
{ 
    GetRideType(
        lon,
        lat,
        item,
        "MIN FARE: 200/=, MAX PASS: 4",
        "Click on the button to request basic ride type.",
        // imageUrl, 
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Basic", value: "Basic"),
        new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Basic", value: "Basic")
        ),
};

return attachment;
```

Can i make it dynamic in a way that the number of cards is predetermined by the size of the array?

Comment: What is `GetRideType` ? Some function which returns an `Attachment`?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide information. What is your array like and what's the logic you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a carousel of cards and lets say you have your data array in a variable called `dataArray`. Just loop through it and create a attachment and add it to `attachment`

Sample code would be :

```
var attachment = new List<Attachment>();
foreach (var data in dataArray)
{
    attachment.Add(
        GetRideType(
            lon,
            lat,
            item,
            "MIN FARE: 200/=, MAX PASS: 4",
            "Click on the button to request basic ride type.",
            // imageUrl, 
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Basic", value: "Basic"),
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Basic", value: "Basic")
        )
    )
}
```